# How to get up to two decimal point for float? Ex- 25.00000

Tags: java

Floating point with more than a zero after the point is not showing up to two decimal point.

I've tried DecimalFormat to convert. It's worked for round up except(with more than a zero) ex- 25.00000

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    Double.parseDouble(df.format(frog_per));
```

I expect the output of 25.00000 to be 25.00, but the actual output is 25.0.

Comment: Where do you output anything? You use `Double.parseDouble` on the result, which turns it into a `double` again

Comment: Like @f1sh said, you should directly print this: `df.format(frog_per)`.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz yapp,,got it.

Comment: Double and float are without any inherent precision (hence _floating_ point). BigDecimal is a _fixed poiint_ class. `new BigDecimal("0.00")` would give a zero with two decimals.

Comment: System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(25.0)); simply works. Besides, be aware what @Joop eggen says.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.format(String format, Object... args)`

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",25.0000));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
25.00
```

Comment: @sohanbappy - do not do this as long as you do not understand the consequences.

Comment: I would NOT recommend using `String.format` to format information to be DISPLAYED. The reason ist that the `DecimalFormat` and the other formatting classes can handle a number of localisation aspects that String.format does NOT. The usage of String.format is therefore only for information which will NEVER be shown in language other then English.

Comment: But that is not what your answer contains.

Comment: The point is, IMHO it is better to point the OP to correct answer to his question - how to use DecimalFormat correctly - then provide - I'm sorry for that expresion - misleading answers like 'use `String.format(String format, Object... args)` for display purpose.

Comment: As I say, I consider the answer misleading.  Therefore I also downvoted.

Comment: Your answer would be ok without the word 'display'.

Comment: there is also a `printf` method which does the formatting and printing together.

Answer (score 0):

https://onlinegdb.com/BJ5W0ibKB

Kindly change DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); to DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");

Answer (score 0):

Your format pattern `0.00` is fine.
 
Just don't construct the double out of the formatted string in order to display it as a formatted output.

`Double` object created from input `25.00` or `25.00000` or `25` is having the value of **25**. It stores the value and never the formatting.

If you want this object to be used to produce `25.00` output you have to format it again, by using either method used in other answers:

```
Double d = 25.00000d;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
System.out.printf("%.2f", d);
```

produces expected output:

```
25.00
25.00
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how u round off 2 decimals.

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
df2.format(variable)
```

Comment: `#` denotes optional decimal digits, so `25.00000` formatted using `.##` format will display `25` - please test